# Attributes assigned globally to advanced search/page sorting/layered navigation on two of my websites. How do I assign them manually?

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation, sorting, advanced-search

I've created two websites, but they will be using two different attribute sets. The products are working fine, as they're only using the attribute set assigned to them. The major issue I'm facing is that all of the attributes I've created, or whenever I create a new attribute, it shows up in advanced search, page sorting, and layered navigation for both sites. I set the attributes scope to "website" or "store", but there's no option to assign it to a specific store or website.

What am I doing wrong and is there a fix for this? I'm having a hard believing Magento allows you to create multiple sites and stores on the same admin, but assigns all the attributes globally no matter what.

#### Example:

- Attribute Set: 1, 2, 3 -
- Attribute Set: 4, 5, 6

Right now layered navigation looks like this:

#### Website #1:

- Attribute 1
- Attribute 2
- Attribute 3
- Attribute 4
- Attribute 5
- Attribute 6

#### Website #2:

- Attribute 1
- Attribute 2
- Attribute 3
- Attribute 4
- Attribute 5
- Attribute 6

When it should looks like this:

#### Website #1:

- Attribute 1
- Attribute 2
- Attribute 3

#### Website #2:

- Attribute 4
- Attribute 5
- Attribute 6

If I change the settings in an attribute to show in advanced search, page sorting, and layered navigation, it automatically assigns them to both sites, which makes no sense.  I'm using Porto for one website, and Ultimo for the other. Any thoughts?